# Caret: Unable to adjust performance metric when using rfe function

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to perform recursive feature elimination using the `rfe` function but I'm having a bit of trouble trying to change the performance measure to output the ROC:

```
newFunc <- caretFuncs
newFunc$summary <- twoClassSummary 

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = newFunc, 
                   method = 'cv',
                   returnResamp = TRUE,
                   number = 2,
                   verbose = TRUE)

profiler <- rfe(predictors, response, 
                sizes = c(1), 
                method = 'nnet',
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=c(4), decay=c(0.1)), 
                maxit = 20,
                metric = 'ROC', 
                rfeControl = ctrl)
```

Trying to run this code is giving me the following error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "undefined columns selected"

If I remove the custom `newFunc`, set the `functions` parameter inside `rfeControl` to use `caretFuncs` and remove the `metric` parameter from `rfe`, the model works fine. This makes me think there's something wrong with the summary.

**caretFuncs$summary:**

```
function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
    if (is.character(data$obs)) 
        data$obs <- factor(data$obs, levels = lev)
    postResample(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
}
```

**twoClassSummary**

```
function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
    lvls <- levels(data$obs)
    if (length(lvls) > 2) 
        stop(paste("Your outcome has", length(lvls), "levels. The twoClassSummary() function isn't appropriate."))
    requireNamespaceQuietStop("ModelMetrics")
    if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == lvls)) 
        stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
    data$y = as.numeric(data$obs == lvls[2])
    rocAUC <- ModelMetrics::auc(ifelse(data$obs == lev[2], 0, 
        1), data[, lvls[1]])
    out <- c(rocAUC, sensitivity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], 
        lev[1]), specificity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[2]))
    names(out) <- c("ROC", "Sens", "Spec")
    out
}
```

The output to `postResample` and `twoClassSummary` are identical in their structures so I'm a little lost as to what this problem is. Am I doing something inherently wrong here or is this a bug that I need to flag to the devs?

---

I'm actually interested in obtaining the `logLoss` so I could write my own function:

```
logLoss = function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  -1*mean(log(data[, 'pred'][model.matrix(~ as.numeric(data[, 'obs'], levels = lev) + 0) - data[, 'pred'] > 0]))
}
```

But, I'm a little unsure how to convert the factor levels into the correct `[0,1]` from my `[yes, no]` factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all here is a viable logloss function for use with caret:

```
LogLoss <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{ 
  obs <- data[, "obs"]
  cls <- levels(obs) #find class names
  probs <- data[, cls[2]] #use second class name
  probs <- pmax(pmin(as.numeric(probs), 1 - 1e-15), 1e-15) #bound probability
  logPreds <- log(probs)        
  log1Preds <- log(1 - probs)
  real <- (as.numeric(data$obs) - 1)
  out <- c(mean(real * logPreds + (1 - real) * log1Preds)) * -1
  names(out) <- c("LogLoss")
  out
}
```

to answer the question how to convert the factor levels into the correct [0,1] from my [yes, no] factor:

```
real <- (as.numeric(data$obs) - 1)
```

to get `rfe` to work you can use `rfFuncs` instead of `caretFuncs`. Example:

```
rfFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, 
                   method = 'cv',
                   returnResamp = TRUE,
                   number = 2,
                   verbose = TRUE)

profiler <- rfe(Sonar[,1:60], Sonar$Class, 
                sizes = c(1, 5, 20, 40, 60), 
                method = 'nnet',
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=c(4), decay=c(0.1)), 
                maxit = 20,
                metric = 'ROC', 
                rfeControl = ctrl)

profiler$results
  Variables       ROC      Sens      Spec      ROCSD      SensSD      SpecSD
1         1 0.6460027 0.6387987 0.5155187 0.08735968 0.132008571 0.007516016
2         5 0.7563971 0.6847403 0.7013180 0.03751483 0.008724045 0.039383924
3        20 0.8633511 0.8462662 0.7017432 0.08460677 0.091143309 0.097708207
4        40 0.8841540 0.8642857 0.7429847 0.08096697 0.090913729 0.098309489
5        60 0.8945351 0.9004870 0.7431973 0.05707867 0.064971175 0.127471631
```

or with the LogLoss function I provided:

```
rfFuncs$summary <- LogLoss
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, 
                   method = 'cv',
                   returnResamp = TRUE,
                   number = 2,
                   verbose = TRUE)
profiler <- rfe(Sonar[,1:60], Sonar$Class, 
                sizes = c(1, 5, 20, 40, 60), 
                method = 'nnet',
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=c(4), decay=c(0.1)), 
                maxit = 20,
                metric = 'LogLoss', 
                rfeControl = ctrl,
                maximize = FALSE) #this was edited after the answer of Дмитрий Пасько) 

profiler$results
  Variables   LogLoss   LogLossSD
1         1 1.8237372 1.030120134
2         5 0.5548774 0.128704686
3        20 0.4226522 0.021547998
4        40 0.4167819 0.013587892
5        60 0.4328718 0.008000892
```

EDIT: Дмитрий Пасько raises a valid concern in his answer - LogLoss should be minimized. One way to achieve this is to provide the logical argument `maximize` telling caret should the metric be minimized or maximized.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Will try this now and get back to you. Any reasons to use `rfFuncs` over the former? And, in regard to my conversion of factors to numerics, I get concerned as `nnet` coerce the factors into `[0,1]` range and it's sometimes hard to be sure which level has been assigned to what. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sam in lack of a batter answer I have to say the reason is rfFuncs works and caretFuncs does not. I could go deeper and check but lack the time at this moment. As for as the coercing of factors in R by different packages, it is usually performed according to the levels of the factor - lowest level == lowest number and so on. This is not a concern here since caret is aware which class nnet predicts on and provides that in `data`, while the custom `LogLoss` function is aware of which class the probability is given.

Comment: @Sam were you able to verify the solution? Did you run into any problems?

Comment: Apologies, can confirm this is a working solution. Many thanks. Do you ever reside in any chats? Not often I find someone who does similar work as me.

Comment: @Sam No problem, glad I could help. Currently I do not have a habit to reside in chats. However feel free to contact me by e-mail, it is in my SO profile and we can arrange a meet in SO or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

but u should minimize logLoss, thus use this code (example with logistic regression https://www.kaggle.com/demetrypascal/rfe-logreg-with-pca-and-feature-importance):

```r
LogLoss <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{ 
  obs <- data[, "obs"]
  cls <- levels(obs) #find class names
  probs <- data[, cls[2]] #use second class name
  probs <- pmax(pmin(as.numeric(probs), 1 - 1e-15), 1e-15) #bound probability
  logPreds <- log(probs)        
  log1Preds <- log(1 - probs)
  real <- (as.numeric(data$obs) - 1)
  out <- c(mean(real * logPreds + (1 - real) * log1Preds)) * -1
  names(out) <- c("LogLossNegative")
  -out
}

lrFuncs$summary <- LogLoss

rfec = rfeControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 2,
                     functions = lrFuncs)
```